# Is there any advanced version of Total Time on Test (TTT) Transform?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, survival, order-statistics, hazard

One parameter survival distribution with increasing hazard rate is (for example) Rayleigh and Lindley, where Rayleigh's hazard rate increases linearly and Lindley's hazard rate increases with a concave trend.

The total time on test (TTT) transform procedure is used as a tool to identify the hazard behavior of the data distribution. As far as I know, the TTT transform can only identify constant, increasing, decreasing, bathtub, and inverse bathtub hazard rate.

I was wondering if there is any more advanced TTT transform that can identify (for example) increasing hazard rate also with their concave/convex trend?